# pdflatex to convert octave code into pdf documents

Tags: pdf, octave, miktex

I am attempting to publish some Octave code as a PDF, however, I keep on getting the same error message:

```
'pdflatex' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

I have also downloaded MikTex now but it still does work when I use the command

```
options.format='pdf';
options.showCode = false;
publish('document1.m',options)
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: The tag wik's of [tag:matlab] and [tag:octave] quite clearly state that unless you're asking about differences/similarities between the two languages you should stick to the one you're actually working in. This is because solutions valid in one language might not be valid in the other even though most might be. I removed the MATLAB references, as your title suggests you're using Octave. Also please don't spam irrelevant tags like [tag:matlab-guide], that's specifically for the GUI-design environment.

Comment: it may be simply a case that you need to put the pdflatex binary in the windows path